# Easiest way to connect the center with a point on the circumference

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have to draw many figures like this:

[image]

with different angles but not for pie charts.

What is the easiest way to draw the lines from the center to the circumference? I searched a lot but only found uber-complicated solutions! I'm sure this must be easy, probably I'm just failing to search for the right keywords. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the circle has radius `r`, you can do this:

```
\draw (origin) -- (angle:r);
```

If the circle is centered at place other than `(0, 0)`, you can do:

```
\draw (location) -- ++(angle:r);
```

---

```
\documentclass[convet = false, tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) circle[radius = 2cm];
  \foreach \i in {0, 30, 80, 150, 270}{
    \draw (0, 0) -- (\i:2cm);
  }

  \draw (5, 0) circle[radius = 2cm];
  \foreach \i in {0, 30, 80, 150, 270}{
    \draw (5, 0) -- ++(\i:2cm);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]